# C fread() of binary file will not read until program is run again

Tags: c, fork, fopen, fwrite, fread

I am working in C language.
my program gets input from user, sends it to a child process, and the child writes those numbers to a binary file. i open the file thusly:

```
FILE *tallyFileW;  
  // open a stream for writing and one for reading
  tallyFileW=fopen("Numbers.bin","ab+"); // to write
  if(!tallyFileW){
    perror("Unable to Open Writing File!");
    return(1);
  }
  else
    perror("File opened to write numbers\n");
```

this goes well; my binary file contains all the numbers I enter. This is how I enter them:

```
void writeNumsToFile(FILE *tallySheet, double aNumber, double aNother)
{
  char twoNumbers[512];
  snprintf(twoNumbers,512,"%lf %lf\n",aNumber,aNother);
  fwrite(twoNumbers,512,1,tallySheet);
}
```

My trouble begins when I go to read those numbers:

```
void getAllNumbers(int fileDesc)
{
  int index,wasRead;
  char numSet[512];
  FILE *getNumbers=fopen("Numbers.bin","rb");

  if(!getNumbers){
    perror("Unable to Open Reading File!");
  }
  else
    perror("File opened to read numbers\n");
  while(fread(&numSet,512,1,getNumbers)==1){
    write(1,numSet,strlen(numSet));
  }
  fclose(getNumbers);
}
```

When I try it right after entering any number of numbers, I get nothing, except (as will be explained below) if it is after the program has already run. This file is opened to append. If it is the first time I'm running the program, nothing prints.

```
please enter your input ---> e
you entered e
Hey, it was fun! See ya later.
File opened to read numbers
: Success
-bash-4.1$ emacs Numbers.bin
```

This ^ is my G'bye dialogue, and then no numbers. But when I run the program again, and exit immediately...

```
please enter your input ---> you entered e
Hey, it was fun! See ya later.
File opened to read numbers
: Success
11.000000 22.000000
33.000000 44.000000
55.000000 66.000000
77.000000 88.000000

-bash-4.1$ rm Numbers.bin
```

What am I missing? I've tried to `fseek()`, but it hasn't worked. I've also written the numbers without newlines, but that didn't help.

Comment: In that question, there is practically no useful information which might help diagnose the problem, so I'll have to fall back on my unreliable crystal ball. The ball is a bit cloudy but it is focussing on the words "child process" in a way which makes me wonder if your reader process is maybe running before the writing process. If the first read executes before the first write, it will see only an end of file, and it will then stop trying to read. But, of course, that's all rampant speculation and any resemblance to reality is purely coincidental. Next time, please, a [mcve].

Comment: do you close the file after writing?

Comment: You could try `fflush(tallySheet)` after the `fwrite`. This should force the buffer to be written into a file. Usually the file writes are buffered for optimization and hence do not take place immediately.

Comment: What is "bupkis"?

Comment: @halfer: yiddish for "beans" but used idiomatically to mean "goat pellets" (that is, excrement) and thus metaphorically to mean "nothing of value", or, as in this case, "nothing". An idiomatic translation to English might be "f... all".

Comment: Very helpful, thanks @rici - I just learned something! I came across "What's the beef with this technique?" here recently, and whilst that works in the US, it probably does not work in India! Some slang just doesn't translate...

Comment: @rici : I discovered the problem. I had been trying to read from the file before closing the write fp (fclose()). I just moved the fclose() call to before calling the read function.

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out yourself, which is probably a much more valuable exercise than just copying a SO response. But if you are inclined to return to SO, please provide a [mcve]. Note that "minimal" does not mean "excerpt"; it should actually be a complete runnable program. Doing that will also help you debug your own problems, and it nay even improve your coding style by teaching you how to separate concerns. So it is overall a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

so the code I had, which was causing problems:

```
if(toupper(buf[0]) == 69){ // its over
  getAllNumbers(fileDesc);
  fclose(tallyFileW);
  close(cli2SirvR);
  close(1);
}
```

and the solution I found:

```
if(toupper(buf[0]) == 69){ // its over
  fclose(tallyFileW);
  getAllNumbers(fileDesc);
  close(cli2SirvR);
  close(1);
}
```

can you spot the difference? I had been closing my write file pointer AFTER I tried to read. Once I moved the write file close to BEFORE I tried to read, all my problems dissipated. Thanks for your help.